# Flexible way of allowing both run-time and compile-time polymorphism?

Tags: c++, templates, design-patterns, c++11, polymorphism

*Example situation:* I'm creating a physics engine intended for game development. I have two types of spatial partitioning methods:

1. Grid
2. Quadtree

---

I want to allow the programmer that is going to use my physics engine to either:

1. Choose the spatial partitioning method at compile-time, via a template parameter

   ```
   Physics::World<Physics::Grid> world; // chosen at compile-time
   ```
2. Choose the spatial partitioning method at run-time, via a polymorphic object

   ```
   Physics::WorldRunTime world; 
   world.setSpatialPartitioningMethod(new Physics::Grid); // chosen at run-time
   ```

---

As you can notice from the above example, I have to use two different classes (`World` and `WorldRunTime`). This leads to code duplication, as I will have a `World` template class without run-time polymorphism and a `WorldRunTime` with run-time polymorphism.

This can be fine.

I'm, however, wondering if there is a **pattern that deals with this issue**, something that allows the programmer to either pass something as a template parameter (compile-time polymorphism) or a polymorphic object (run-time polymorphism) with minimal code duplication.

Some sort of *policy pattern* where policies can be chosen both at compile-time or run-time?

---

Example desired (?) code:

```
{
    // *** Compile-time world
    // No overhead
    Physics::World<Physics::Policy::CompileTime, Physics::Grid> world;
}

{
    // *** Run-time world
    // Allows run-time spatial partitioning method swapping
    // Suffers from run-time polymorphism overhead
    Physics::World<Physics::Policy::RunTime> world;
    world.setSpatialPartitioningMethod(new Physics::Grid);
}
```

Notice how in both blocks I'm using the same class, in order to avoid having to write two classes and duplicate code. Is there any way something like the above code can be implemented?

Comment: Assuming that the time taken in the spatial partitioning method is much greater than the time required to select the spatial partitioning method, then you should use only run-time selection in order to simplify the code.

Comment: @NeilKirk: true, this is only an example. The question is just a technical curiosity.

Comment: Maybe add a dummy option which can be used as a template parameter. When the dummy option is selected, it uses a run-time method that must be selected.

Comment: In your static polymorphism example, is your user locked into a default-constructed `Physics::Grid`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For runtime polymorphism, instantiate the template with a polymorphic base class that the various concrete policies derive from.

To encourage devirtualization when runtime polymorphism isn't used, mark the concrete policy classes as `final`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is pretty attainable as long as you're willing to make `Physics::Policy::CompileTime` a template. This is totally uncompiled as I don't have enough of your code to attempt to compile for a real use case.

```
template <typename Child>
struct CompileTime
{
    void operation1(int v) { child_.operation1(v); }
    void setSpatialPartitioningMethod(PhysicsPolicy* policy) {} // No work on static policy.

    Child child_;
};

struct RunTime
{
    RunTime() : policy_(0) {}
    void setSpatialPartitioningMethod(PhysicsPolicy* policy) { policy_ = policy; }
    void operation1(int v) { policy_->operation1(v); }

    PhysicsPolicy* policy_;
};

template <typename Policy>
class World
{
public:
    void setSpatialPartitioningMethod(PhysicsPolicy* policy) { policy_.setSpatialPartitioningMethod(policy); }

private:
    Policy policy_;
};


{
    // *** Compile-time world
    // No overhead
    Physics::World<Physics::Policy::CompileTime<Physics::Grid> > world;
}

{
    // *** Run-time world
    // Allows run-time spatial partitioning method swapping
    // Suffers from run-time polymorphism overhead
    Physics::World<Physics::Policy::RunTime> world;
    world.setSpatialPartitioningMethod(new Physics::Grid);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As a mental exercise, I wanted to see if I could get as close as possible to your desired syntax with one extra constraint: I didn't want to incur the cost of a vtbl pointer or the vtbl itself if compile time was selected. The other solutions here so far will correctly bind at runtime or compile time, but they will still generate the vtbl and increase the size of the World object by a sizeof(pointer) even if you select `Policy::CompileTime`

This is the best I could come up with so far:

One big downside of this is that Grid becomes a template class because I needed to make it optionally inherit from PhysicsPolicy (to avoid the vtbl generation).

There is one minor delta between your desired syntax and what is below: I needed to instantiate the runtime Grid with an empty template list, ie. `new Physics::Grid<>`

I've overridden operator-> so that world->findObject() will call the method, without having to write a whole bunch of extra methods -- The alternative would be to add a definition for each method in PhysicsPolicy into `Policy::Runtime`.

```
struct Point3 { float x, y, z; };

namespace Physics
{
    // This is a dummy base class used to avoid vtbl creation for Grid
    class Empty { };

    class PhysicsPolicy
    {
    public:
        virtual void* findObject(const Point3& p) = 0;
    };

    template<typename BASE=PhysicsPolicy>
    class Grid : public BASE
    {
    public:
        void* findObject(const Point3& p) { return nullptr; } // Just a placeholder
    };

    namespace Policy
    {
        template<template<typename> class T> class CompileTime
        {
        public:
            T<Empty>* operator->() { return &obj; }

        private:
            T<Empty> obj;
        };

        // This is just here so that an empty template parameter list is possible
        template<template<typename> class... T> class RunTime;
        template<> class RunTime<>
        {
        public:
            void setSpatialPartitioningMethod(PhysicsPolicy* aP) { p = aP; }
            PhysicsPolicy* operator->() { return p; }

        private:
            PhysicsPolicy* p;
        };
    }

    // The desired syntax has the number of parameters dependent upon the policy
    // This is done using c++11's variadic templates, and passing the extra
    // parameters into Binding
    template<
        template<template<typename> class...> class Binding,
        template<typename> class... U>
    class World : public Binding<U...>
    {
    public:
    };
}

int main()
{
    Physics::World<Physics::Policy::CompileTime, Physics::Grid> compileTimeWorld;

    Point3 p{1,2,3};
    printf("%p\n", compileTimeWorld->findObject(p));

    Physics::World<Physics::Policy::RunTime> runTimeWorld;
    runTimeWorld.setSpatialPartitioningMethod(new Physics::Grid<>);
    printf("%p\n", runTimeWorld->findObject(p));

    return 0;
}
```

Note: tested against clang. No idea if it'll work on other compilers